# what is difference between (define (add x y) (+ x y)) and (define add (lambda (x y) (+ x y)))?

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

I am now writing a scheme's interpreter by using c++. I got a question about define and lambda.

```
(define (add x y) (+ x y))
```

is expanded as

```
(define add (lambda (x y) (+ x y)))
```

by [lispy.py](http://norvig.com/lispy2.html)

what's the difference between this two expression?

why need expand the expression? Just because it is easy to evaluate the expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same, since one gets expanded into the other.  The first expression is easier to both write & read; having it expand into the second simplifies the interpreter (something you should appreciate).

Comment: It's *likely* that "one gets expanded into the other", but that's not a requirement.  The standard (R5RS, at least) just says that they're equivalent.  An implementation could choose to recognize both without doing any syntactic expansion.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Was going by what was stated in OP.

Comment: Yes, I notice now that OP is citing a specific interpreter that's a sort of Lisp-language, and not necessarily exactly Scheme.  The question is tagged with [tag:sicp], which suggests a proper Scheme (hence why [I appealed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27788961/1281433) to the R5RS standard), but it looks like [tag:sicp] may well be a mis-tag.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent in R5RS:

> ### [5.2  Definitions](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%25_sec_5.2)
>
> ```
> (define (<variable> <formals>) <body>)
> ```
>
> <Formals> should be either a sequence of zero or more variables, or a
>   sequence of one or more variables followed by a space-delimited period
>   and another variable (as in a lambda expression). This form is
>   equivalent to
>
> ```
> (define <variable>
>   (lambda (<formals>) <body>)).
> ```